# When I added z-index: 999 value gets converted to an order

Tags: css, gulp

Recently I came up with an issue. When I added a z-index of 999 it converted to an ordering number.

Example

If added a `z-index: 9999` first element this converts to `z-index: 1` 
Then when I added `z-index: 9999` to the second element this converted to `z-index: 2`

and so on. I never and cannot use `999` as a `z-index`.

This is a project that was done by someone else and I'm doing new changes.

Using gulp for CSS compile.

Comment: where do you track that the z-index is converted?? z-index is like a layer

Comment: Are you certain that the z-inde is actually converted, as opposed to being used in a relative fashion?

Comment: @c.m . I checked my .css and inspect elements.

Comment: @AHaworth yes I check my css also. it compiles to an order. Is it may be some gulp plugin used?

Comment: Yes, if you search “gulp changes z-index” you will find a lot of stuff out there. It seems gulp tries to clean up (in its eyes) the z-indexes. Frankly I don’t see how that is safe given new indexes may be created dynamically, and it can’t possibly know about this at compile time. I don’t know whether this dangerous  activity can be overridden.

Comment: @AHaworth i found the solution. need to change ```cssnano()``` to ```cssnano({zindex: false})```.Refer the link below. Thanks

https://github.com/antonybudianto/angular-starter/issues/172#issue-188218454

Answer (score 1):

Need to change `cssnano()` to `cssnano({zindex: false})`. In gulp js file

Refer the link below.

https://github.com/antonybudianto/angular-starter/issues/172#issue-188218454